# achartengine - Android the curve displayed from right to left

Tags: android, achartengine

My application requires graph library and I am using achartengine graphe library.

the problem that curve begin from right to left but i have to display it from left to right.
what did i have to change ??

Answer (score 0):

You asked this several days ago, but I thought I'd answer in case you or another has a similar issue.

I, too, noticed this when I began using `AChartEngine`. I solved it by iterating through my data array in reverse order. Obviously I don't have your code, but I'd suggest trying something along these lines.

```
for (int tIndex = tData.length-1; tIndex >= 0; --tIndex)
{
     tXYSeries.add(tIndex, tData[tIndex]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution:

It's initialization before start, I add the two lines below and it works well.

```
mRenderer.setXAxisMax(10000);
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
```